# Android activity to open camera and upload an image to a server

Tags: php, android, android-camera, image-uploading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling camera from an activity, capturing an image and uploading to a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679571/calling-camera-from-an-activity-capturing-an-image-and-uploading-to-a-server)

Here is the code i got on internet:

```
package com.android.imageuploader;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import com.android.imageuploader.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageUploaderActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    private Button button_1;
    public int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private ImageView image_view;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        image_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        button_1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        button_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            try {
                // We need to recyle unused bitmaps
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                }
                InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                        data.getData());
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                stream.close();
                image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

this shows a button and an imageView(contains default image initially) and when i click on the button it takes me to the gallery and when i click on any of the images that image is given to the imageView.
I have two questions here:
1.how to make the button take me to the camera and when i capture an image
2.upload it directly to a web server

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="pickImage"
        android:text="Button" >
    </Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/wic_logo_small" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When user clicks the button you need to open a camera through intent e.g.

```
    public int TAKE_PICTURE =1
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
```

and in onactivityresult you will get that image which you captured from your camera.

Now you have to upload that image to server

plz go through the following url

[Android post Base64 String to PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920967/android-post-base64-string-to-php/9921230#9921230)

Comment: 1 thing i didnt understand...where is the code using the button to be clicked???...here in the code i cant find any button(this is the only class in the app) but when i run itand click on the button which is in the xml file it takes me to the gallery

Comment: you have to edit that xml and add one button & set it's on click listener in which write the above code.

Comment: no...what i mean is the code i pasted in my question works perfectly as the way i explained....but there is no button in the whole code...so how am i able to click it and go to the gallery???

Comment: can u paste that main.xml file

Comment: see in xml file android:onClick="pickImage" this is written when u click on button it will call "pickImage" method.  how that works u can look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4153517/how-exactly-does-the-androidonclick-xml-attribute-differ-from-setonclicklistene

Comment: I changed my code....1s chk the question pls...does this work???....i am working on an emulator so cannot test camera