# Android - Encoding image and sending it to the server

Tags: android, encoding, client-server, base64, http-post

I am working on encoding the selected image from the gallery and want to send it to the server.
I succeeded to send name and description of the product which is text form.
but, I don't know how to encode image and send it to string form.
On the server side, I need to decode it with php.
My code is...

```
public class AddEditWishlists extends Activity {

// Client-Server - Start //////////////////////

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// url to create new product
private static String url_create_product = "http://10.56.43.91/android_connect/create_product.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
InputStream is;
// Client-Server - End //////////////////////


//Define Variables
private EditText inputname;
private EditText inputnote;
private Button upload;
private Bitmap yourSelectedImage;
private ImageView inputphoto;
private Button save;
private int id;
private byte[] blob=null;
byte[] image=null;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_wishlist);
    setUpViews();
}

private void setUpViews() {

    inputname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputname);
    inputnote = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputnote);
    inputphoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.inputphoto); 

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        id=extras.getInt("id");
        inputname.setText(extras.getString("name"));
        inputnote.setText(extras.getString("note"));

        image = extras.getByteArray("blob");

        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(image , Base64.DEFAULT);

        if (image != null) {
            if (image.length > 3) {
                inputphoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length));
            }
        }       
    }



    //Image Upload Button
    upload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.upload);
    upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });




    // Save the data
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    // Save하면 발생되는 이벤트
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (inputname.getText().length() != 0) {
                AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object> saveContactTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
                        saveContact();



                        // Client-Server - Start //////////////////////////////////////
                        String name = inputname.getText().toString();
                        String description = inputnote.getText().toString();
                        //String photo = inputphoto.getContext().toString();
                        encodedImage = yourSelectedImage.toString();

                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
                        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", encodedImage));

                        Log.v("log_tag", System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");



                        // getting JSON Object
                        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params1);

                        // check log cat fro response
                        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

                        // check for success tag
                        try {
                            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);


                            Log.v("log_tag", "In the try Loop" );

                            if (success == 1) {
                                // closing this screen
                                finish();
                            } else {
                                // failed to create product
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }



                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                        finish();
                    }
                };

                saveContactTask.execute((Object[]) null);

            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        AddEditWishlists.this);
                alert.setTitle("Error In Save Wish List");
                alert.setMessage("You need to Enter Name of the Product");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
                alert.show();
            }
        }
    });
}


// If users save data, this will act (data -> db) 
private void saveContact() {

    if(yourSelectedImage!=null){
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStr = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        yourSelectedImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStr);
        blob = outStr.toByteArray();
    }



    else{blob=image;}

    // Change Text type to string type to save in the DB
    SQLiteConnector sqlCon = new SQLiteConnector(this);

    if (getIntent().getExtras() == null) {
        sqlCon.insertWishlist(inputname.getText().toString(), inputnote.getText().toString(), blob);
    }

    else {
        sqlCon.updateWishlist(id, inputname.getText().toString(), inputnote.getText().toString(), blob);
    }


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent resultdata) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, resultdata);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = resultdata.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);

            cursor.close();
            // Convert file path into bitmap image using below line.
            yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
            inputphoto.setImageBitmap(yourSelectedImage);
        }

    }
}
```

what I am working on is the part here

```
if (extras != null) {
        id=extras.getInt("id");
        inputname.setText(extras.getString("name"));
        inputnote.setText(extras.getString("note"));

        image = extras.getByteArray("blob");

        //Here..I encoded the image ***********Is it correct?**********
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(image , Base64.DEFAULT);

        if (image != null) {
            if (image.length > 3) {
                inputphoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image,0,image.length));
            }
        }       
    }
```

and...

```
                        // Client-Server - Start //////////////////////////////////////
                        String name = inputname.getText().toString();
                        String description = inputnote.getText().toString();

// this line should be modified i guess....                                           
String encodedImage = yourSelectedImage.toString();

                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params1 = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                        params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));


// This line should be modified i guess..
params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", encodedImage));

                        Log.v("log_tag", System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");



                        // getting JSON Object
                        // Note that create product url accepts POST method
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product, "POST", params1);

                        // check log cat fro response
                        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
```

I wrote annotation where should be corrected....
I think that part makes error..

and one more question is that on the server side, how format should it be to receive the encoded photo? Varchar? char?..

Thank you in advance.

Comment: search for how to send multipart data to server from android.

Comment: why this question is associated with multipart data?

Comment: this is the conversion,String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(image , Base64.DEFAULT);   now after sometime you are overriding the value of encodedImage in the onclick method of save button as   encodedImage = yourSelectedImage.toString(); so remove this second line of code.

Comment: remove this line you mean? "encodedImage = yourSelectedImage.toString();"

Comment: if i remove this line, it makes error because "params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", encodedImage));" in this line "encodedImage is not defined.

Comment: very appreciate with your help anyway Ice Box..!!! im moved!!

Comment: make that variable global then.

Comment: do this if you already haven't done it yet, `String encodedSelectedImage = Base64.encodeToString(yourSelectedImage, Base64.DEFAULT); .... params1.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo", encodedSelectedImage));`