# How to save image through capturing in android to php?

Tags: java, php, android, bitmap, arrays

We have tried this code for android and php. Please see below code.

**Android**

```
Scn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        // Open default camera
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                // start the image capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(intent, 100);
            }
 }
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
            if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


                 selectedImage = intent.getData();
                    imageBitmap = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, baos);

                imageView1.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

               submitData(encodedImage);         
           }
}

public void submitData(final  String encodedImage) {
        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        //Looper.prepare();
                        Log.d("looper", "-->>>>");
                        try 
                        {
                            isAuthorized = isAuthenticated(encodedImage);
                        } 
                        catch (Exception e) 
                        {
                            Log.e("Exception ==> ", e.toString());  
                        }
                        MHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    if(isAuthorized){
                                        if(AuthenticationResultJSONObject!=null){
                                            String message = AuthenticationResultJSONObject.getString("message");

                                            if(AuthenticationResultJSONObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(ScannerActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                            else if (AuthenticationResultJSONObject.getString("status").equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                                            {
                                                Toast.makeText(ScannerActivity.this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        Toast.makeText(ScannerActivity.this, "Loing unsuccessfull, please try again !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } 
                                catch (Exception e) 
                                {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                    Log.e("Exception 146==> ", e.toString());  
                                }
                                finally 
                                {

                                    //progressdialog.dismiss();
                                    //progress.dismissProgressDialog();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("Exception 153==> ", e.toString());  
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception 159==> ", e.toString());  
        }
    }
    public boolean isAuthenticated(final  String encodedImage) 
    {
        isAuthorized = false;
        String encoder1 = "";
        final String url="http://bestpeopleservice.com/projects/scanner/api/api/api.php?class=login&method=login_data&json=";


        String finalurl = "{\"data\":{\"qr_code\":\""+username1+"\",\"user_pass\":\""+password1+"\",\"longitude\":\""+longitude1+"\",\"latitude\":\""+latitude1+"\",\"adderss\":\""+adderss1+"\",\"images\":\""+encodedImage+"\"}}";//
        Log.v("267 1111111", "done url -> "+url+finalurl);

        try {
            encoder1 = URLEncoder
                    .encode(finalurl,"UTF-8");
            Log.v("267 222", "done url 2 -> "+url+encoder1);
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
                try {

                    if (isNetworkConnected()) {

                        AuthenticationResultJSONObject = new JSONObject(doFetchDataFromWebService_Simple_OnlyJSONResponse(url+encoder1));    

                        Log.v("Online", "User json array    ===  "+AuthenticationResultJSONObject);  

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(ScannerActivity.this, "Please check your internet connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
                catch(Exception e){ 
                    e.getMessage();
                }
                finally{
                    if(AuthenticationResultJSONObject!=null){
                        isAuthorized = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        isAuthorized=false;
                    }
                }
        //  }
    //  });
        return isAuthorized;
    }

    // Checking the internet connection
    public boolean isNetworkConnected() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivitymanagar = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkinfo = connectivitymanagar.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkinfo == null || !networkinfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }



    public String doFetchDataFromWebService_Simple_OnlyJSONResponse(
            String WebServiceURL) {

        String responseBody = "";
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject();
        try {
            HttpGet WSHttpPost = null;
            HttpClient WSHttpClient = null;
            HttpResponse WSHttpResponse = null;

            WSHttpClient = getNewHttpClient();
            WSHttpPost = new HttpGet(WebServiceURL);
            WSHttpResponse = WSHttpClient.execute(WSHttpPost);

            Log.d("resp", ""+WSHttpResponse);
            //responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(WSHttpResponse.getEntity());
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(WSHttpResponse.getEntity(), "UTF-8");


            Log.v("response1", "" + responseBody);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Exception2 ==> ", e.toString());
        }
        if (responseBody == null || responseBody.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return responseBody;
        }
    }

    public HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        try {
            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore
                    .getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);

            SSLSocketFactory sf = new MySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, registry);

            return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new DefaultHttpClient();
        }
    }

    public class MySSLSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        public MySSLSocketFactory(KeyStore truststore)
                throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
                KeyStoreException, UnrecoverableKeyException {
            super(truststore);

            TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain,
                        String authType) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
            };

            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { tm }, null);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket(Socket socket, String host, int port,
                boolean autoClose) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(socket, host,
                    port, autoClose);
        }

        @Override
        public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
            return sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket();
        }
}
```

It returns parsing bytestring. Its value is too much long.

**PHP**

```
 $base=$Data['images'];
 $binary=base64_decode($base);
 header('Content-Type: bitmaps; charset=utf-8');
 header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($base, '8bit'));
 $file = fopen('qr_code.jpeg', 'wb');
 fwrite($file, $binary);
 fclose($file);
 echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory';
```

Above code is working. But it have some issue. Image save successfully in folder but image will be displayed as corrupted. How can we resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: save that image in some folder

Comment: Default it will be save in our root folder. But It will be shown in corrupted format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code this code working for me.

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . '/xyz/' . '/' . $target_path;


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    // reading other post parameters
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';

    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $response['email'] = $email;
    $response['website'] = $website;

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not and Android developer.

But I know the problem is with your request. You are passing all data in `GET` request method (appending parameters in URL). But It has limitation of 2,083 character length. (It depends on webserver actually)

So, If your image size is higher than that, it will simply truncate from URL.

For the solution, you have to use `POST` request to submit data to webservice.

**Android**

Refer answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920967/android-post-base64-string-to-php) for android code snippet

**PHP code**

```
<?php

$json=json_decode($_POST['json']); //decoding json which is received from Android.

$photo=$json->images; //get image data (which is encoded in base64)

/* Decoding image */
$binary = base64_decode ( $photo );

/* Opening image */
$file = fopen ( 'file_name_to_create.jpeg', 'wb' );

/* Writing to server */
fwrite ( $file, $binary );

/* Closing image file */
fclose ( $file );

?>
```

It will create `file_name_to_create.jpeg` in current directory.

*Reference*

1. [Maximum Length of GET request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers)
2. [POST request using Android](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient)

Comment: @kruti, The problem is with URL Encoding i guess. I suggest you to echo your data from php, and log it in android logcat. Post encoded image in your question.

Comment: @kruti did you changed GET method to POST ?

Comment: We have tried with post method. But it will be save image in folder but file size is 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67300/discussion-between-ravi-dhoriya--and-kruti).

Answer (score 1):

Hi i have used this approach to save myImage.

- **Create images folder inside your root.**

  $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");

  $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

  $extension = end($temp);

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../images/" . $varFileName);
- **Use this URL to download my code for sending imagefile to php server.**

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D6874F5E96BBF5A8!17174&authkey=!AIA5xGcRI7UnyNg&ithint=folder%2cjar

```
     final Dictionary<String, String> dictionary = new Hashtable<String, String>();
     dictionary.put("name", "kruti");
     dictionary.put("file", "file");
```

Comment: why are you using HTTP_GET , use HTTP POST .

Comment: We have tried your code. but it does not send any response and also image is not save in folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67304/discussion-between-tushar-pandey-and-kruti).