# File not uploading to server due to httpResponse

Tags: java, php, android, servlets, httpresponse

```
/**
 * Uploading the file to server
 * */
private class UploadFileToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // setting progress bar to zero
        progressBar.setProgress(0);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        // Making progress bar visible
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // updating progress bar value
        progressBar.setProgress(progress[0]);

        // updating percentage value
        txtPercentage.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]) + "%");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return uploadFile();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(“http://www.example.com/example/fileUpload.php”);//example site

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            // Adding file data to http body
            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            // Extra parameters if you want to pass to server
            entity.addPart("website",
                    new StringBody("www.androidhive.info"));
            entity.addPart("email", new StringBody("abc@gmail.com"));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            // Making server call
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Server response
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Response from server: " + result);

        // showing the server response in an alert dialog
        showAlert(result);

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}

/**
 * Method to show alert dialog
 * */
private void showAlert(String message) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(message).setTitle("Response from Servers")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // do nothing
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

PHP CODE FOR SERVER fileUpload.php

```
<?php

// Path to move uploaded files
$target_path = "uploads/";

// array for final json respone
$response = array();

// getting server ip address
$server_ip = gethostbyname(gethostname());

// final file url that is being uploaded
$file_upload_url = 'http://' . $server_ip . '/' . 'AndroidFileUpload' . '/' . $target_path;


if (isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
    $target_path = $target_path . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    // reading other post parameters
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
    $website = isset($_POST['website']) ? $_POST['website'] : '';

    $response['file_name'] = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    $response['email'] = $email;
    $response['website'] = $website;

    try {
        // Throws exception incase file is not being moved
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
            // make error flag true
            $response['error'] = true;
            $response['message'] = 'Could not move the file!';
        }

        // File successfully uploaded
        $response['message'] = 'File uploaded successfully!';
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['file_path'] = $file_upload_url . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Exception occurred. Make error flag true
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // File parameter is missing
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = 'Not received any file!F';
}

// Echo final json response to client
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Above code response to client below error:

httpResponse is not responding. Exception come as org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond.
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Comment: The php server is online? Does have some http header sniffing (by htaccess) to refuse call?

Comment: yes php server is online. m not getting this point "Does have some http header sniffing (by htaccess) to refuse call?"

Comment: Have you setted an .htaccess on php web server?

Comment: We have set .htaccess in our root folder but not setted in subfolder. Need to set .htaccess

Comment: maybe the .htaccess on root folder is stopping the request?

Comment: what to do for this ?

Comment: better you test that API in any RestClient or Advance Rest Client in browsers, check the responce from the server.. to know the exact problem...

Comment: Stick to your [**old question**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27546608/how-to-save-image-through-capturing-in-android-to-php), unless you are facing some different problem. Keep updating your existing question, what all you are trying and whats happening. It will help people to solve your problem. **Don't repeat same question.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code:

```
// Making server call
  HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
  HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

  int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
  if (statusCode == 200) {
  // Server response
  responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
} else {
  responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
  + statusCode;
}

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
  responseString = e.toString();
} catch (IOException e) {
  responseString = e.toString();
}
```